# Tratamento de casos de teste negativos com JEST

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tdd, jest

Tenho um código em Jest que deve testar uma regra de negócio que diz:

> Nenhum cliente deve ter CPF inválido

```
it(" should not be able to create a new user whith a wrong CPF",async()=>{

    const repositoryFake = new FakeUserRepository();

    const createUserService = new CreateUserService(repositoryFake);

    expect(await createUserService.execute({
        name:"Joao Geraldo da Cruz",
        password:"321",
        cpf:"50989120003",
    })).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(Error)
})
```

Porém, ao executar a chamada o serviço, ele quebra o código:

```
public async execute({name, password, cpf}:IUserInterface):Promise<User> {

    if (cpf) {
        if (!DocumentValidation.cpf(cpf)) {
//ele cai nessa validação aqui
            throw new Error("CPF not is valid");
        }
    }

    const user = await this.repository.create({
        name, password, cpf
    });

    return user;
}
```

Realmente era esperado que o sistema quebrasse, porém o Jest deveria entender isso como "normal" e retornar sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu caso, se você espera que `createUserService.execute` lance um *Rejection Error* (*Promise* que foi rejeitada), você deveria usar o `await` antes do `expect`, isso implica dizer para o Jest esperar que uma função assíncrona seja rejeitada (`rejects`) e comparar o retorno dessa rejeição:

```js
await expect(createUserService.execute({
      name:"Joao Geraldo da Cruz",
      password:"321",
      cpf:"50989120003",
  })).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(Error)
```

Tem a [documentação do Jest](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait) que explica isso usando `async/await`.

Para o `rejects` ter efeito, a função passa para `expect` tem que retornar uma *Promise* e do jeito que você colocou, o `await` espera a função retornar um resultado em vez de termos uma promise para o `expect`, temos um objeto *Error*, logo o `rejects` não irá funcionar pois o objeto do `expect` não é uma promise.

Comment: resolveu aqui Obrigado!!!