# Falha ao testar throw new Error com jest e Nodejs

Tags: node.js, jest

Estou criando testes unitários para uma api de cadastro de produtos, porém, quero testar se ao tentar remover um produto e retornar um array vazio (sinal de que não encontrou o produto), será lançado um erro, estou usando o throw new Error() do JS, mas sempre que executo o meu teste está falhando.

Método na minha classe

```
 const product = await db.query(sqlSelect, {
  replacements: {
    id_restaurant: idRestaurant,
    id_product: idProduct,
  },
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
});

if (product.length === 0) {
  throw new Error("Produto não encontrado");
}

const sql =
  "delete from products p where p.id_product = :id_product and p.id_restaurant = :id_restaurant";

await db.query(sql, {
  replacements: {
    id_restaurant: idRestaurant,
    id_product: idProduct,
  },
  type: QueryTypes.DELETE,
});

return { success: true };
```

Meu suite de teste

```
it("should throw an error if the product does not exist", async () => {
const { sut } = createInstance();
const idProduct = 1;
const idRestaurant = 1;
db.query.mockResolvedValue([]);

expect(await sut.removeProduct(idProduct, idRestaurant)).rejects.toThrow(
  "Produto não encontrado"
);
```

Ao executar o teste estou recebendo este erro e o teste falha:

```
 Produto não encontrado

  80 |
  81 |     if (product.length === 0) {
> 82 |       throw new Error("Produto não encontrado");
     |             ^
  83 |     }
  84 |
  85 |     const sql =

  at Product.removeProduct (src/controllers/products/index.js:82:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/product.test.js:143:12)
```

Aparentemente está entrando corretamente na condição do if, mas não entendi o motivo do teste falhar.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Tratamento de casos de teste negativos com JEST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/502865/tratamento-de-casos-de-teste-negativos-com-jest)

Answer (score -1):

Tu está passando o **valor resolvido da Promise** para o método `expect`, ao invés de passar a **própria Promise**, o que impede o método de lidar com o possível erro.

Ao invés de

```js
expect(await func()).rejects.toThrow(...);
```

Faça

```js
await expect(func()).rejects.toThrow(...);
```

[Veja sobre o modificador `rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects)

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!